# How to pass one object to another

Tags: java, selenium

In my test class (Test.java) I create object variables: loginPage and homePage.
In HomePage class I create Field object: emailField with value: "something"
How can I get "emailField" value (and the entire object as well) inside HomePage class?

When i try to use emailField.getValue() or loginPage.emailField in getEmailValue() method I get errors: Cannot resolve symbol 'emailField'/Cannot resolve symbol 'loginPage'

Test.java:

```
public class Test extends GeneralTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        HomePage homePage = loginPage.logIn(loginPage);
        homePage.getEmailValue();
    }
}
```

HomePage.java:

```
public class LoginPage{
    private Field logInField = new Field(FieldType.INPUT, By.id("test1"));
    public Field emailField = new Field(FieldType.INPUT, By.id("test2"));
    private WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        emailField.setValue("something");
        getSite("https://apply.commonapp.org/login");
    }

    public HomePage logIn(Object object){
        //some actions
        driver.findElement(logInField.getSelector()).click();
        return new HomePage(driver);
    }
}
```

HomePage.class:

```
public class HomePage{
    private WebDriver driver;

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void getEmailValue(){
        // emailField.getValue() -> Cannot resolve symbol 'emailField'
        // loginPage.emailField -> Cannot resolve symbol 'loginPage'
    }
}a
```

Comment: You probably want to find a basic tutorial on Java, and figure out inheritance.

Comment: you can use Dependency Injection for this, but I would re-consider the use of Page-Object-Model at this point... and ditch the @test annotation, "Field", and extended class. 
 (those are generally used with a framework of some sort) Selenium is a time-line based series of actions, which means you can use a much more direct, script-like approach.  If you find that you need to re-use some components, you can develop class objects, base classes and dependency injection and build an architecture which suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

###### How to pass one object to another

`emailField` is `LoginPage` class variable, you can access it via `LoginPage` object instance.

For passing objects to some classes the basic way is to set them in constructor.
The same you've already done for driver.

```
public class HomePage{
    private WebDriver driver;
    private LoginPage loginPage;

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver, LoginPage loginPage){
        this.driver = driver;
        this.loginPage = loginPage;
    }

    // not sure what this method should do, but if it called get.. by naming conventions it should return something, so I changed it's type to Field and added return. But it's up to you, you may leave void, this is not related to your question.
    public Field getEmailValue(){
         return loginPage.emailField; // now this will work
    }
}
```

Do not forget to pass LoginPage object instance when instantiate
HomePage.

```
public class LoginPage{
    private Field logInField = new Field(FieldType.INPUT, By.id("test1"));
    public Field emailField = new Field(FieldType.INPUT, By.id("test2"));
    private WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        emailField.setValue("something");
        getSite("https://apply.commonapp.org/login");
    }

    public HomePage logIn(Object object){
        //some actions
        driver.findElement(logInField.getSelector()).click();
        return new HomePage(driver, this); // this means current class instance
    }
}
```

---

###### Some tutorials

https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_constructors.asp
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/constructors.html